# Return laravel query results in chunks

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have an Update model in my Laravel/Vue.js app, instead of retrieving and displaying all results at once in my component, I want to return them in chunks of fives and place a *NEXT FIVE UPDATES* link in my component to display the next 5 update records, much like in pagination. I tried this:

```
$update = Update::limit(5)->get();
```

This does not achieve my desired result. Is there a Laravel method i can use in my laravel backend to send the results in chunks of 5 to my Vue.Js component and then make my NEXT *FIVE UPDATES* link display the next 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to send some kind of page or offset value to the backend then you could use laravel's skip and take methods: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
$skip = $request->page; //assuming this variable exists...
$limit = 5;
$update = Update::skip($skip * $limit)->take($limit)->get();
```